# Errors in AngularJS often causes infinite loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Often when I get an error in Angular it causes an infinite loop in the browser and can lock down everything until I can kill the process. This tends to happen mostly when calling a function from a template with something like an ng-show.

```
<div ng-show="ifCanTakeAction()">
    <button ng-click="takeAction()></button>
</div>
```

If the function *ifCanTakeAction* gets an exception then it might become an infinite loop.

Obviously it is fairly easy to just fix the error in *ifCanTakeAction* but it is highly irritating that my computer goes for a short siesta every time it happens.

I am guessing the loop appears due to dirty-checking. Something in the crash of *ifCanTakeAction* causes another round of checks, which crashes it again, ad infinitum. Or it just dirty-checks that fires continuously. But how do you avoid this error? Is it simply ill-advised to run the function from the template like that? Often I would assign a model in the controller instead and look at that, but sometimes you have a case where the result might change as the user interacts with the page, which is why I base it on a function instead.

So, is this correct? Is it the dirty-checking that causes this issue? Would a watch do better (I assume that would get the same basic problem)? Is there a good way to catch and prevent infinite loops in general?

Comment: reason for using function `result might change` doesn't make sense. If properly scoped, a variable in `ng-show` works fine and will be watched by angular

Comment: How so? It will work if I update it when needed of course, but a $watch should have the same issues. Should I go for using $broadcast to change things like this instead?

Comment: I.e. the issue would then be how to update the model on the scope.

Comment: Not clear what changes are you need to follow. Can you make demo in plunker that outlines problem. Is this a nested isolated scope issue?

Comment: A demo probably wouldn't be very representative I'm afraid, since you can cause the error in much simpler conditions. But I'll try to add some more info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifCanTakeAction()` should be replaced with a flag `canTakeAction`. Not only this will solve browser crashing, it will perform better. Currently angular is forced to call that function on every digest cycle. It makes much more sense to use a boolean value and to update it in controller when needed.

Comment: Sure, but what if canTakeAction is liable to change while the user interacts with the page (and is complex enough that it needs to be checked by a function)?  I would need a watch, and won't the behaviour of a $watch in the controller be basically the same thing? or is a watch more efficient?

Comment: Perhaps I should work more with broadcasts. Do one when changing things that can affect canTakeAction and then run the function based on that. Then the digest loop has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes, using watch would make it more or less the same. Although I cannot say for sure if that's the case. On the other hand, using events would be best performance-wise.

Comment: Which is problematic since what I wanted to avoid was having to put in a function call on everything that might change this, since it is too easy to miss one. But I guess the answer might come down to, "don't design stuff like that in the first place" :P

Comment: Or wait, a watch actually would be less likely to fail. I could watch the parts of the scope the function depends on and only run the function when there is an actual change. Even if an error happened the second digest loop would just report no changes on the scope and the function would not be called again. So doing in the controller would be more stable if done properly (even if a watch still is not efficient).